# UnsafeMutablePointer as an output argument in PyObjC

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

In PyObjC when the function is void I can pass None as the output argument and then I will get the output argument in the returned value but when it comes to a function that is non void I can't find an example how it's done. What I'm trying to do is to get the GlyphBuffer in the following function from an already initiated instance of a NSLayoutManager. Here is the syntax in Objective c:

```
NSInteger numGlyphs = [layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
NSGlyph *glyphs = (NSGlyph *)malloc(sizeof(NSGlyph) * (numGlyphs + 1)); 
[layoutManager getGlyphs:glyphs range:NSMakeRange(0, numGlyphs)];
[textStorage removeLayoutManager:layoutManager];
```

As you can see the glyphs is an array of NSGlyphs with a length returned by layoutManager numberOfGlyphs. I got the following method to work in python:

```
layoutManager.getGlyphsInRange_glyphs_properties_characterIndexes_bidiLevels_ (glyphsRange, None, None, None, None)
```

But I don’t get the glyph buffer in return because the function is not void, instead it returns the number of glyphs in glyphBuffer as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403104-getglyphs). The glyph buffer should be an UnsafeMutablePointer. I can’t find a way to pass a NSGlyph array to the second argument. When I pass a list I get a traceback:

```
ValueError: depythonifying 'pointer', got 'list'
```

Does anyone know if it’s possible and how it could be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was trying to extract position of glyphs in the LayoutManager I used locationForGlyphAtIndex method of the LayoutManager and it worked fine for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this blog at

http://michaellynn.github.io/2015/08/08/learn-you-a-better-pyobjc-bridgesupport-signature/

it should have some examples of how to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Read the whole thing, no idea how to alter the sig for a method.